# Video sorting workflow

Tags: windows, workflow

In windows 7, I used to use windows explorer to click on a video, press the play button, and decide if it was worth keeping. If it was worth keeping, I'd move it to a "use" folder.

However, Windows 10 explorer doesn't seem to support this play feature. Without this function in Windows 10 explorer, I have to open many videos in a media player to view them, find the filename of the one I'm viewing, then go back to explorer to move to the "use" folder.

1) I've looked for a way of re enabling this feature in explorer, but don't seem to be able to do this. Is it possible?

2) Is there other software that's a file manager and viewer combined? I can not seem to find one.

Comment: Interesting workflow +1 for showing me a really easy way to flick through videos.

Answer (score 0):

what you are looking for is a DAM (Digital Asset Management) software. There are many many options available some free some paid.

Most NLE's have this built in, again there are free and paid versions

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, however, I'm keen just to have a file manager type application with a built in play video option, so I don't have to open up a seperate video player to quickly sort the good and bad clips.

Comment: Directory Opus can preview videos inline, but it's paid.

Comment: Don't be fooled into thinking that one piece of DAM software will solve all of your Digital Asset Management problems.  That's equivalent to saying that one piece of IT software will answer all of your Information Technology problems.  DAM is a profession that's large enough to support an entire industry.  If you don't believe me, check out the size of their conferences.  https://digitalassetmanagement.com/blog/22-conferences-for-dam-professionals-to-attend-in-2018/

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the workflow you described in Windows 10.

Firstly, you will need to set Windows Media Player as the default video player for that file type:

[image]

To change the default, click "Choose another app" and then select "Always use..." at the bottom:

[image]

Next, enable the "Preview Pane" in windows explorer:

[image]

Now, when you click on a video file of the right file type, it will be playable in the preview pane:

[image]

Note: this feature only works for local files.  Cloud files such as those on onedrive / dropbox that aren't downloaded won't show up.

In regards to your second point, if you use any Adobe programs you may find Adobe Bridge bundled with them.  Bridge is an Adobe type file explorer that can natively open many files, and also open them directly in the relevant Adobe editing software.